# Is there an equivalent of the ActionResult RedirectToAction for ViewResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have looked at previous questions but I could not find an answer to this particular scenario: I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 with a TDD approach. On my action methods, I use the return type of ViewResult opposed to ActionResult. This is fine to test my controllers. However, I need to test my view models as well as my controllers. I can do this quite happily by using the Model property on the ViewResultBase (which is implemented ViewResult but not ActionResult) for my model tests.

If there view model is null then I would like to redirect to another action. ActionResult supports a RedirectToAction method. However, ViewResult does not. I have tried the View method but the url does not change in the browser address bar. Also, I even tried the classic ASP.Net Response.Redirect(...), unsurprising, my unit test complains that the Response object has not been populated.

So, what approach do I use to achieve the equivalent of the ActionResult RedirectToAction for ViewResult?

Comment: Are you using the [MVC Contrib Test Helper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper)?

Comment: No, just the standard Microsoft unit test suite that ships with VS 2010 Pro

Comment: It automatically creates certain objects like the `HttpResponse` object, so you can easily unit test controllers.  It might help you not have to change your result type according to your development strategy and be able to use `ActionResult` instead.  I've used it a few times in the past and it's allowed me to create tests that otherwise would be near impossible to create.

Comment: Does it happily integrate with TFS for automated builds?

Comment: Not sure, it works fine with out TeamCity builds, couldn't say for TFS, might be worth a look into though.

Comment: I found another way to do it. I set my action method return type to ActionResult and then within both branches of the if statement I redirected to another action (using RedirectToAction) with the return type of ResultView. I changed the initial unit test to handle ActionResult but created two more unit tests for action result that gave me the model for each side of the branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it. I used the following steps:

1. I set my action method return type to ActionResult
2. I changed its unit test to use ActionResult
3. I created two additional action methods with the return type of ResultView.
4. For each branch of the if statement of action method from [1], I redirected to the appropriate action method in [3], I used RedirectToAction to redirect.
5. I create two unit tests that use ResultView to test the action methods created in [3] and give me access to the underlying Model for each.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to return more than one result type from a controller, then set its return type to action result and then assert that the different conditions create the right result type.

For instance, in AJAX actions, you may want to return HttpStatusCodeResults to set the response property to errors should validation fail or there be an exception.

Then when the action has succeeded, you may want to return a partial view for display with the result.

Using this approach you can tailor your logic in your controller and still assert the different results are correct.

Comment: How does this help me run tests that implement ViewResultBase? ActionResult does not.